# docker-compose > v.3 search volume_from analog

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i try to migrate from v.2 docker-compose file to v3.3
early i can write somthing like that

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
      - php

  php:
    build:
      ./docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./:code
```

now volume_from dont exist and i must do somthng like that

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
     volumes:
      - ./:/code
  php:
    build:
      ./docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
```

i dont like this way, i wish have one volumes for two container, i'm RTFM the docker docs and try do next

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8014:80"
    volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: data
          target: /code
  php:
    build:
      ./docker/php
    volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: data
          target: /code

volumes:
    data:
```

But, of couse i dont have any files in `data` how i can put's all my files from `./` to `data` ?